# What is the difference between BPF and eBPF?

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf

I'm new to eBPF, and there are a lot of tutorials saying eBPF is just the extended BPF, but I cannot understand what `extended` mean? So what is the difference between BPF and eBPF? Are the samples resides in Linux source file `[root]/samples/bpf` examples of eBPF or just BPF?

Answer (score 8):

**BPF** is sometimes used to refer to eBPF (created [in 2014](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg296893.html)) and sometimes to cBPF (its predecessor [from 1991](https://www.tcpdump.org/papers/bpf-usenix93.pdf)). As Qeole noted, you can find a [detailed comparison of the two](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.17/bpf/classic_vs_extended.html) in the kernel documentation.

---

**cBPF** (classic BPF) is a small bytecode with two 32-bit registers to perform basic filtering on packets and syscalls. No state can be persisted between two calls to a cBPF program.

cBPF is still used by e.g. seccomp and tcpdump, but is actually translated to eBPF bytecode in the recent kernels.

---

**eBPF** (extended BPF) is a new bytecode with significant extensions. The bytecode has a more "modern" form, with 10 64-bit registers, fall-through jumps, and a stack space, enabling easier JIT-compilation to native instruction sets. It can call special functions, called *helpers*, to interact with the kernel. It can save state to *maps* using those helpers. It comes with a new syscall, `bpf(2)`, to manipulate BPF objects (e.g., maps, programs, etc.). A good introduction to the eBPF ecosystem is available at [ebpf.io](https://ebpf.io).

eBPF programs can be written in C and compiled to the bytecode using LLVM/Clang. The [examples in the kernel sources](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.9/source/samples/bpf) are eBPF programs.